# C: traversing tree_nodes in a directory tree

Tags: c, list, ls, treenode

I am building a traversable directory tree.

This diagram I drew will help you understand the structure easily:

[image]

How do you print out a list of subdirectories (subDir) of the current working directory (cwd)?

So for example, I would use the shell commands in this order:

```
mk_directoryName, cd_directoryName, ls
```

Below is my code attempt for the method 'cd', but it seems to stay in the root directory and print ALL DIRECTORIES and not ONLY SUBDIRECTORIES of cwd:

```
// *checks whether cwd has a subdirectory named arg
// *if yes, the function returns the corresponding tree node (and become new working directory)
// *if no, prints an error message
// *handle cd and cd ..
struct tree_node *do_cd(struct tree_node *cwd, struct tree_node *root, char *arg) {

    // checks if cwd has a subdirectory named arg
    struct list_node *subDir = cwd -> first_child;

    struct tree_node *parDir = cwd -> parent;
    printf("Making current working directory the parent directory.\n");

    while (subDir != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(subDir -> tree -> string_buffer, arg) == 0) {
            printf("Subdirectory exists: Entering!\n");
            cwd = subDir-> tree;
            printf("Making subdirectory current working directory: name = %s\n", arg);
            printf("Returning current working directory: %s.\n", arg);
            return cwd;
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg, "..") == 0) {
            cwd = parDir;
            printf("Returning to parent directory.\n");
            return cwd;
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg, "") == 0) {
            printf("Returning to root directory.\n");
            return root;
        }
        subDir = subDir-> next;
    }
    printf("Directory does not exist!\n");
    return cwd;
}
```

ls print method code attempt:

```
// prints all children of the directory cwd (not recursively)
void do_ls(struct tree_node *cwd) {
    printf("Listing Directories...\n");
    struct list_node *subDir = cwd -> first_child;
    while (subDir != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", subDir ->tree -> string_buffer);
        subDir = subDir->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: several of the questions/answers on stackoverflow are about reading the directory entries.  The key factors are `DIR` `opendir()`, `readdir()`  and `closedir()` with header file: `dirent.h`.   Suggest read the man pages for those functions and search stackoverflow for those keywords.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently Traverse Directory Tree with opendir(), readdir() and closedir()](//stackoverflow.com/q/2312110/90527)